# В зависимости от значения вывести несколько процессов

Tags: c, c++

Привет.

Как сделать так, чтобы вывелось несколько процессов (pid1, pid2 ,pid3...), в зависимости от значения, введенного через printf. Например:

```
printf("Vvedite chislo processov\n");
scanf("%d",n);

Через for вывести как-то не получилось... Листинг кода:

SHDATA *data = shdata_open();

if (data) {

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stack_push(data, temp[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stack_push(data, temp[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    pid3 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stack_push(data, temp[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @marioxxx, Вы хотите запустить в \*nix n процессов ?

Если да, то делайте в цикле for и **завершайте дочерний процесс не return, а exit**.

Comment: И не надо вопрос засовывать в код

Comment: @niki-timofe, это у @marioxxx очевидно (от нетерпения ?) рука дрогнула, когда он выделял мышью текст программы.

--

@marioxxx, соберетесь отреагировать, заодно осветите что и **как** делают функции stack_push() и shdata_open(). А то ведь не факт, что в параллельных процессах все будет правильно работать.

Comment: stack_push() заносит элемент в стек как обычно.
shdata_open открывает разделяемую память и семафор, затем инициализирует разделяемую память.

Comment: Цикл for(i=0;i<n;i++). В цикле for вместо return 0 вставить exit. exit с каким параметром? Если по умолчанию то не работает

Comment: @marioxxx, поясните, что Вы хотите сделать?  
>сделать так, чтобы вывелось несколько процессов
 
По вашему вопросу неясно, хотите Вы выводить куда-то информацию одновременно из нескольких процессов, или вы просто несколько процессов хотите запустить.

Comment: Есть родительский процесс он 1!!!
Мне надо вывести дочерние процессы в n-ом количестве . Сверху есть код, там клонируются процессы несколько раз через fork().

Comment: @marioxxx, 

    stack_push() заносит элемент в стек как обычно

А второй аргумент это что ? Ссылку на документацию приведите. IMHO это какая-то Ваша функция. Она с семафором в data работает ?

Comment: в двух словах,
data - название стека, temp[i] набор чисел куда заносятся...

Comment: как несколько определенных клонов создать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@marioxxx](/users/5491/marioxxx), не знаю, что такое определенные клоны. Откуда Вы такую терминологию берете ?

Вот пример программы с процессами (делал в Linux). Собирайте, запускайте, читайте маны.
Обратите внимание, что значения переменых наследуются, но изменения в одном прцессе не влияет на значение переменной в другом. Если непонятно, что для чего в ней нужно - спрашивайте.

Shared memory это отдельная большая тема. Если пока можете без нее, то лучше без. Передавать данные между процессами можно по pipe-s.

gcc nforks.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int   n, i;
  pid_t pid;

  if ((n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):2) < 1)
    n = 2;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (pid = fork()) {
      if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit (-1);
      }
      printf ("Run child %ld i = %d\n",(long)pid,i);
    } else {
      // child
      printf ("Child %ld started in loop %d\n", (long)(pid = getpid()),i);
      if (pid & 1)
        exit (i);   // вернуть можно только целые от 0 до 255 !!!
      kill (pid,9); // kill himself
    }
  }

  int st;
  while ((pid = wait(&st)) > 0) {
    printf ("Child %ld terminated ",(long)pid);
    if (WIFEXITED(st))
      printf (" with code %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(st));
    else
      printf (" by signal %d\n",WTERMSIG(st));
  }

  perror("wait");
  printf ("End pid = %ld\n",(long)pid);
}
```

Comment: printf ("Run child %ld i = %d\n",(long)pid,i); Это запуск i-го child-а? А почему преобразуете в long?

Comment: Для совместимости (чтобы gcc не выводил warning для printf()) между 32 и 64-бит ОС. Посмотрите в /usr/include/... на определение pid_t.

Comment: if ((n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):2) < 1). Здесь как проверка происходит?

Comment: Если аргументы командной строки не введены, то av[1] будет NULL. 

Исходя из этого проверяем, если агумента нет, то (по умолчанию) запустим 2 процесса. Если в аргументе фигня (число меньше 1 или вообще буквы), то тоже по умолчанию.

--

Про операцию **?** в C Вы, надеюсь, читали.

Comment: про тернарный оператор да